# ArcGIS - separate/split shapefiles by attribute range and save

Tags: arcgis-desktop, classification, select-by-attribute, reclassify, split-by-attribute

**Problem**:
I often have a shapefile that I classify into 3-5 classes based on the values of a specific field. Usually I am interested how many features are in each class and which area has each of the classes.

**How I solve it**: My workflow to solve it was to use the "Select by Attribute" to get one class, then make a layer from the selection and do the statistical calculations, then eventually save it as separate shapefile.
I have to redo these steps for each class.

**Question how it could be solved more efficient**:  I was wondering if ArcGIS provides a tool how this can be solved in a more efficient way. I know of the tool "Split by attributes" but the problem is, that my classes often are not given by a single field value, but include a range. Imagine a shapefile with rivers where I classify them into small (<5m), medium (5-20m) and large (>20m). I would need to set the field to the width, but to include a range and not making every single field value to split the shapefile. Maybe I would have to reclassify these values first, but is there a tool to reclassify based on a shapefile and not a raster?

I know that it could be easily solved by a small script, but I was thinking that many people could have this problem and maybe I overlooked the appropriate tool.

Comment: Field Calculate a new field small, medium, large and split by attributes on this. How many classes do you have? You have an example like yours [here](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/tables/calculate-field-examples.htm): Classify based on field values.

Comment: thanks for your comment. The "relcassification" using the field calculator makes sense.

Comment: If  I understand correctly, it is more the question to find the appropriate tool to get the job done? Otherwise, if you want to avoid scripting you could build a small model in the model builder that you can rerun when needed.

Comment: yes exactly, I am asking if there exists a tool or not. I thought so many people will have this issue and it would be strange if ArcGIS does not provide a simple user friendly interface for it. As an experienced GIS user and programmer, for me it's no problem to make a python script, but I thought maybe a tool exists that I have overlooked